# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/SessionNotFoundException

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I am using Firefox 45.0 and Dependency added in `pom.xml` is
`selenium-firefox-driver 2.53.0`.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/SessionNotFoundException
    at TestFIles_MDM.Test_Authn.setup(Test_Authn.java:27)
```

Error is coming for both Firefox and Chrome.

How can I resolve it, it was working last week.

Comment: Are you trying to se the webdriver instance after it was closed, perhaps?

Comment: it looks like your browser and webdriver version not in sync.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are missing this dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Check [Selenium docs about Maven dependencies](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp).

Comment: I have this dependency too in my pom.xml:


  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.0</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: that should be enough. Try to include selenium-api dependency explicitly maybe and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: did that too, but still not running.   selenium-api:     2.39.0

Comment: why not selenium-api 2.53.0 (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-api/2.53.0/)

Answer (score 2):

Voila, It's worked for me.Just updated the selenium-java dependency in pom.xml

```
<!--  Selenium java-jar dependency -->

<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>2.53.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Or here is the link to get the updated version-
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java

Answer (score 2):

Run `mvn dependency:tree` in your project, and check what is transitively depending on `selenium-remote-driver`.

In my project, I was correctly depending on `selenium-java` at `2.53.1`, but another test dependency was depending on an older version (2.40.0); that meant my tests were using the `2.40.0` version of `selenium-remote-driver` at runtime, which causes the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/SessionNotFoundException` error.

If you have transitive dependencies on `selenium-remote-driver`, you have two options for "fixing" them:

1. Update the artifact that's depending on the older version to either

   - Not depend on the artifact at all, or
   - Use the latest version.
2. Add an entry in your `pom.xml`'s `<dependencyManagement>` section for `selenium-java` to peg the artifact at version `2.53.1`.

   This will affect the version of `selenium-java` both in your project and all your nested maven dependencies, too; be aware that those nested artifacts may not work well with the latest version!

It's also worth mentioning that `selenium-java` version `2.53.0` had a Firefox incompatibility problem; version `2.53.1` allegedly fixes that. See http://seleniumsimplified.com/2016/06/use_selenium_webdriver_jar_locally/ for more details.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

This happened with me while trying to update to remote driver to 3.0.1 from 2.53.1. I just reverted it back to 2.53.1 and it went away

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
<version>2.53.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this too. I changed to the following and it went away.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0-alpha-2</version>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```