# How to run Selenium automated tests with HtmlUnit driver and Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, htmlunit-driver

Not able to configure and run `Selenium` tests after configuring `HtmlUnit` driver in my `Spring Boot` application.

Getting an error when I execute the test.

**BaseSeleniumTests.java**

```
public abstract class BaseSeleniumTests {

    protected static String BASE_URL = "";
    private static final String URL_PROPERTIES = "url.properties";
    protected WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        //load test properties
        Properties p = loadAppTestProperties();
        BASE_URL = p.getProperty("base.url");
        System.out.println("BASE_URL = " + BASE_URL);

        //load driver
        this.driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    }

    private Properties loadAppTestProperties() {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        String filePath = classLoader.getResource(URL_PROPERTIES).getFile();
        File f = new File(filePath);
        try {
            Properties p = new Properties();
            p.load(new FileReader(f));
            return p;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

}
```

**HomePageTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class HomePageTest extends BaseSeleniumTests {

    @Test
    public void testHomePage() {
        this.driver.get(BASE_URL);
        String htmlSource = this.driver.getPageSource();
        assertTrue(htmlSource.contains("US Router"));
        assertTrue(htmlSource.contains("Welcome to JPMorgan Chase"));
    }

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.52.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/SessionNotFoundException

    at com.jpmchase.gct.ft.BaseSeleniumTests.loadHtmlUnitDriver(BaseSeleniumTests.java:71)
    at com.jpmchase.gct.ft.BaseSeleniumTests.setUp(BaseSeleniumTests.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: You try [adding the missing dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698363/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-openqa-selenium-remote-sessionnotfoundexcept)? You've not listed a verison number on your selenium-java dependency. `mvn dependency:tree` should let you see what your dependencies are and if any are marked transitive.

Comment: `Spring Boot` automatically picks the latest dependency hence no need to mention the dependencies unless you want override it. In my case it pulled in `3.9.1` dependency of `chrome, firefox, ie, edge, safari, remote-driver` etc. It did NOT pull in `htmunit-driver` hence had to put the latest one available from `maven` repo explicitly.

Comment: No, Spring Boot does not automatically pick the latest dependency. It picks the dependency that's specified in the BOM (bill of materials.) So in order to know the dependency version, you need to know the version of the BOM being used, and if there are any other dependencies which override that.

Comment: Is the `BOM` version the `spring-boot-starter-parent` version which in my case is `2.0.6.RELEASE`?