# Unable to run the script through htmlunit driver in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I'm trying to run the htmlunit driver but It's failed to execute the script

Code:

```
 public class Testworking 
  {

    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
     {
        WebDriver driver=new HtmlUnitDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
     }

  }
```

Exception:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/SessionNotFoundException
  at com.online.paypal.test.sampler.Testworking.main(Testworking.java:10)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  ... 1 more
```

And my pom.xml file looks like below:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.2</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

Is anybody have idea why I'm getting invocation target exception, and how can I over come this issue. I just want to done this requirement only using htmlunit not with phanthomjs or other headless driver. I just want to launch the sample google.com without support of any chrome or firefox driver only using htmlunit and the VM didnt have any browser (Chrome or firefox binaries) and I just want to run it through htmlunit.

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: 1. Have you refreshed your dependencies?

2. Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698363/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-openqa-selenium-remote-sessionnotfoundexcept

Comment: It really helps

Comment: @ArrchanaMohan - Just want's to know which VM you are using which doesn't supports Chrome/Firefox browsers and phatomjs ?

Comment: I didnt say it wnt support I dont have access to ssh those machines. Its GCP accounts, We can't ssh those directly. Also, we cant get any public images from global repository. Also those environments are dockerized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to beatrice for yours comments. I just removed some unnecessary dependencies from pom.xml also observed that htmlunitdriver is available in v3.4.0 by default. We no need to add that explicitly in pom.xml. I did clean install, and updated the maven project (.m2) cleaned and updated again.

It resolved the issue.

Thanks for all your inputs and comments.